# Resolve hostname from IP on Android

Tags: java, android, network-programming, android-networking

I have a problem that I'm dealing with from a long time... I'm creating an Android app that will get info of devices that are in the same subnet as an Android device.
For example I give it ip address 192.168.0.3 and it shows that its hostname is xxxx and MAC Address xx:xx:xx... .

I have managed to read MAC address but I fail with hostname...
I have tried

```
InetAddress.getHostname()
InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()
```

And it is returning always an IP address...
I have also tried jmDNS library but its just returning "ipaddress.local"

How can I get NETBIOS name of devices in my network?
Please, help :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress